# How can I tell the Data Annotations validator to also validate complex child properties?

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

Can I automatically validate complex child objects when validating a parent object and include the results in the populated `ICollection<ValidationResult>`?

If I run the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Person
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        [Required]
        public string Street { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string State { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person = new Person
            {
                Name = null,
                Address = new Address
                {
                    Street = "123 Any St",
                    City = "New York",
                    State = null
                }
            };

            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(person, null, null);
            var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

            var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(person, validationContext, validationResults);

            Console.WriteLine(isValid);

            validationResults.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r.ErrorMessage));

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

> `False`
>   `The Name field is required.`

But I was expecting something similar to:

> `False`
>   `The Name field is required.`
>   `The State field is required.`

---

I offered a bounty for a better child object validation solution but didn't get any takers, ideally

- validating child objects to an arbitrary depth
- handling multiple errors per object
- correctly identifying the validation errors on the child object fields.

I'm still surprised the framework doesn't support this.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006516/support-for-nested-model-and-class-validation-with-asp-net-mvc-2-0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to make your own validator attribute (eg, `[CompositeField]`) that validates the child properties.

Comment: This is the approach I am trying and it works, but I am hung up on the fact that the attribute can only return 1 ValidationResult.  

This is an issue if the child has multiple validation errors. I can stuff the error messages into a single string but it seems messy and wrong.

Answer (score 58):

#### Issue - Model Binder Order

This is, unfortunately, the standard behavior of [`Validator.TryValidateObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772.aspx) which

> does not recursively validate the property values of the object

As pointed out in Jeff Handley's article on [Validating Object and Properties with the Validator](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2009/10/16/validator.aspx), by default, the validator will validate in order:

1. Property-Level Attributes
2. Object-Level Attributes
3. Model-Level implementation `IValidatableObject`

The problem is, at each step of the way...

> If any validators are invalid, `Validator.ValidateObject` will abort validation and return the failure(s)

#### Issue - Model Binder Fields

Another possible issue is that the model binder will only run validation on objects that it has decided to bind.  For example, if you don't provide inputs for fields within complex types on your model, the model binder won't need to check those properties at all because it hasn't called the constructor on those objects.  According to Brad Wilson's great article on [Input Validation vs. Model Validation in ASP.NET MVC](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html):

> The reason we don't "dive" into the Address object recursively is that there was nothing in the form that bound any values inside of Address.

#### Solution - Validate Object at the same time as Properties

One way to solve this problem is to convert object-level validations to property level validation by adding a custom validation attribute to the property that will return with the validation result of the object itself.

Josh Carroll's article on [Recursive Validation Using DataAnnotations](http://www.technofattie.com/2011/10/05/recursive-validation-using-dataannotations.html) provides an implementation of one such strategy (originally in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7665862/1366033)).  If we want to validate a complex type (like Address), we can add a custom `ValidateObject` attribute to the property, so it is evaluated on the first step

```
public class Person {
  [Required]
  public String Name { get; set; }

  [Required, ValidateObject]
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

You'll need to add the following **ValidateObjectAttribute** implementation:

```
public class ValidateObjectAttribute: ValidationAttribute {
   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {
      var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
      var context = new ValidationContext(value, null, null);

      Validator.TryValidateObject(value, context, results, true);

      if (results.Count != 0) {
         var compositeResults = new CompositeValidationResult(String.Format("Validation for {0} failed!", validationContext.DisplayName));
         results.ForEach(compositeResults.AddResult);

         return compositeResults;
      }

      return ValidationResult.Success;
   }
}

public class CompositeValidationResult: ValidationResult {
   private readonly List<ValidationResult> _results = new List<ValidationResult>();

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Results {
      get {
         return _results;
      }
   }

   public CompositeValidationResult(string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage) {}
   public CompositeValidationResult(string errorMessage, IEnumerable<string> memberNames) : base(errorMessage, memberNames) {}
   protected CompositeValidationResult(ValidationResult validationResult) : base(validationResult) {}

   public void AddResult(ValidationResult validationResult) {
      _results.Add(validationResult);
   }
}
```

#### Solution - Validate Model at the Same time as Properties

For objects that implement `IValidatableObject`, when we check the ModelState, we can also check to see if the model itself is valid before returning the list of errors.  We can add any errors we want by calling `ModelState.AddModelError(field, error)`.  As specified in [How to force MVC to Validate IValidatableObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6431986/1366033), we can do it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Model model) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        var errors = model.Validate(new ValidationContext(model, null, null));
        foreach (var error in errors)                                 
            foreach (var memberName in error.MemberNames)
                ModelState.AddModelError(memberName, error.ErrorMessage);

        return View(post);
    }
}
```

> **Also**, if you want a more elegant solution, you can write the code once by providing your own custom model binder implementation in Application_Start() with `ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(new CustomModelBinderProvider());`.  There are good implementations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7523993/1366033) and [here](http://www.haneycodes.net/trigger-ivalidatableobject-validate-when-modelstate-isvalid-is-false/)

Comment: Great answer. Nevertheless it really sucks that it cannot be done out of the box with like setting an option.

Comment: Could this solution be amended to work with unobtrusive javascript?

Comment: @JasonlPrice, pedantically, I'm sure it *could* be, but I'm not sure what edge cases you're having trouble with.  Can you post a test case and an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question?

Comment: @KyleMit I have created a question at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064842/create-a-complex-type-model-validation-attribute-with-server-and-client-validati

Answer (score 12):

I also ran into this, and found this thread. Here's a first pass:

```
namespace Foo
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;

    /// <summary>
    /// Attribute class used to validate child properties.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493800/how-can-i-tell-the-data-annotations-validator-to-also-validate-complex-child-pro
    /// Apparently the Data Annotations validator does not validate complex child properties.
    /// To do so, slap this attribute on a your property (probably a nested view model) 
    /// whose type has validation attributes on its properties.
    /// This will validate until a nested <see cref="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute" /> 
    /// fails. The failed validation result will be returned. In other words, it will fail one at a time. 
    /// </remarks>
    public class HasNestedValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Validates the specified value with respect to the current validation attribute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value to validate.</param>
        /// <param name="validationContext">The context information about the validation operation.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// An instance of the <see cref="T:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult"/> class.
        /// </returns>
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var isValid = true;
            var result = ValidationResult.Success;

            var nestedValidationProperties = value.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(p => IsDefined(p, typeof(ValidationAttribute)))
                .OrderBy(p => p.Name);//Not the best order, but at least known and repeatable.

            foreach (var property in nestedValidationProperties)
            {
                var validators = GetCustomAttributes(property, typeof(ValidationAttribute)) as ValidationAttribute[];

                if (validators == null || validators.Length == 0) continue;

                foreach (var validator in validators)
                {
                    var propertyValue = property.GetValue(value, null);

                    result = validator.GetValidationResult(propertyValue, new ValidationContext(value, null, null));
                    if (result == ValidationResult.Success) continue;

                    isValid = false;
                    break;
                }

                if (!isValid)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```