# Entity Framework - Validation (server + clientside, jquery) with data annotations, WITHOUT MVC?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, validation, jquery-validate, data-annotations

there are several tutorials that explain how to use EF data annotation for forms validation using the MVC framework. And to use jquery for the client side.

See e.g.: http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/clientvalidation_mvc2.htm

I would like to achieve the same, but without using MVC/MVC2.

I want to build a classic asp.net site, create the Entities Model, create my partial classes that include the validation (required, regex etc.).

I created the entities model and the partial classes including the data annotations. I can add new records to the DB.

What I miss is the validation. Now I can add records to the DB even if the fields are not valid, I would like to get the errors, and if possible  I would like to use jquery for the client validation (in MVC you just add `<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>` to the view...).

Can you help me? Or point me to some good online resources that explain this?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**: I found something here:

[How can I tell the Data Annotations validator to also validate complex child properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493800/how-can-i-tell-the-data-annotations-validator-to-also-validate-complex-child-prop)

I have an Entity called "User" and I created a partial class as follows:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MySite.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
    public partial class User
    {
    }

    public class UserMetaData
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username Required")]
        [DisplayName("Username")]
        public string Username{ get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password Required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[^;>;&;<;%?*!~'`;:,."";+=|]{6,10}$", ErrorMessage = "The password must be between 6-10 characters and contain 2 digits")]
        public string Password{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the code behind of my page I've put a similar "isValid" check as in the above mentioned link:

```
var validationContext = new ValidationContext(person, null, null);
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(userToAdd, validationContext, validationResults);

if (isValid)
{
savetoDB();
}
```

But when I debug... "isValid" is always "true", even if I leave the fields null. Help :-S

EDIT2:

It was always "true" because I was filling the "user" properties, as follows:

```
User userToAdd = new User();
userToAdd.Username = txtUsername.Text;
userToAdd.Password = txtPassword.Text;
```

I changed the object: from "User" to "UserMetaData" (`User userToAdd = new UserMetaData();`) then the validation works ("false" in case the regex is not respected) ... but still, quite weird... then I should create another "User" object and fill it again... not very clean...

Answer (score 0):

You've probably found a solution or moved on by now, but I created an open source project that does exactly this - MVC style validation with Data Annotations attributes and jQuery Validate.

http://xvalwebforms.codeplex.com

You'll be interested in the jQuery.Validate branch. Its not quite complete yet, but very close. Here's an example from the demo project:

**Model**

```
public class Booking : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Client name is required.")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Client name must be less than 15 characters.")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 20, ErrorMessage = "Number of guests must be between 1 and 20.")]
    public int NumberOfGuests { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Arrival date is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Arrival date is invalid.")]
    public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Smoking type is requried.")]
    public SmokingType SmokingType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Email address is invalid.")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    #region IValidatableObject Members

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (ArrivalDate == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Arrival date is required.", new[] {"ArrivalDate"});
        }

        // Business rule: Can't place bookings on Sundays
        if (ArrivalDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Bookings are not permitted on Sundays.", new[] {"ArrivalDate"});
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**ASPX Markup**

```
    <fieldset class="booking">
        <legend>Booking</legend>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="valSummary" runat="server" CssClass="ui-state-error" />
        <val:ModelValidator ID="valBooking" runat="server" CssClass="validator" Display="Dynamic"
            ModelType="xVal.WebForms.Demo.Booking" />
        <label for="txtClientName">
            Your name:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClientName" runat="server" />
        <val:ModelPropertyValidator ID="valClientName" runat="server" CssClass="validator"
            ControlToValidate="txtClientName" Display="Dynamic" PropertyName="ClientName"
            ModelType="xVal.WebForms.Demo.Booking" />
        <label for="txtNumberOfGuests">
            Number of guests:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumberOfGuests" runat="server" />
        <val:ModelPropertyValidator ID="valNumberOfGuests" runat="server" CssClass="validator"
            ControlToValidate="txtNumberOfGuests" Display="Dynamic" PropertyName="NumberOfGuests"
            ModelType="xVal.WebForms.Demo.Booking" />
        <label for="txtArrivalDate">
            Arrival date:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtArrivalDate" runat="server" CssClass="date-picker" />
        <val:ModelPropertyValidator ID="valArrivalDate" runat="server" CssClass="validator"
            ControlToValidate="txtArrivalDate" Display="Dynamic" PropertyName="ArrivalDate"
            ModelType="xVal.WebForms.Demo.Booking" />
        <label for="txtEmailAddress">
            Email address:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server" />
        <val:ModelPropertyValidator ID="valEmailAddress" runat="server" CssClass="validator"
            ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress" Display="Dynamic" PropertyName="EmailAddress"
            ModelType="xVal.WebForms.Demo.Booking" />
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" /></div>
    </fieldset>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsValid)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (txtNumberOfGuests.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        txtNumberOfGuests.Text = "1";
    }

    Booking booking = new Booking
                          {
                              ClientName = txtClientName.Text,
                              NumberOfGuests = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfGuests.Text),
                              ArrivalDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtArrivalDate.Text),
                              EmailAddress = txtEmailAddress.Text
                          };

    BookingManager.PlaceBooking(booking);
}
```