# ValidationResult Returned From IValidatableObject.Validate Is Not Localized

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, ivalidatableobject

In my ASP.NET MVC3 site, I am using the following as a View Model:

```
using DataResources = Namespace.For.The.Localization.Resources.IndexViewModel;

public class IndexViewModel, IValidatableObject {

    private string _field1_check_value = "foo";
    private string _field2_check_value = "bar";

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="Validation_Field1_Required", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(DataResources))]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="Validation_Field2_Required", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(DataResources))]
    [DataType(DataType.Field2)]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
        if (!(Field1.Equals(_field1_check_value) && Field2.Equals(_field2_check_value))) {
            string[] memberNames = { "Field1", "Field2" };
            yield return new ValidationResult(DataResources.Validation_InvalidCredentials, memberNames);
            }
        }
    }
```

When the site is viewed using any culture other than the default, the `Required` validation messages are properly localized. However, the message returned from the `Validate` method are always in the default culture.

Is there a way to properly localize the `IValidatableObject.Validate` messages?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the `IValidatableObject.Validate` method is called before the culture is available to the system. If the `Validate` method is called manually from the controller action, the error messages are properly localized.

Using a variation of the method listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431478/), I can get localized error messages into the view by clearing the ModelState and forcing the validation to be run again in the controller action as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel viewModel) {

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        //Do Stuff
        return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
        }
    else {
        // The original validation did not properly localize error messages coming from IValidatableObject.Validate.
        // Clearing the ModelState and forcing the validation at this point results in localized error messages.
        ModelState.Clear();
        var errors = viewModel.Validate(new ValidationContext(viewModel, null, null));
        foreach (var error in errors)
            foreach (var memberName in error.MemberNames)
                ModelState.AddModelError(memberName, error.ErrorMessage);
        }

    return View("Index", viewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Where are you setting the Culture? I set it in Controller > ExecuteCore and it works as expected.

e.g.

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override void ExecuteCore()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = "en-GB"; 
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");

            base.ExecuteCore();
        }
  }
```