# Validate that an entered date is older than today's date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got an Html.TextBoxFor element where a user can enter their birthdate.  I want to make sure they only enter a date that is older than today's date.  Here is the validation I have in my model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Birthdate is required")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$", ErrorMessage = "Please use MM/DD/YYYY")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public System.DateTime Dob { get; set; }
```

and here is the relevant part of my view:

```
<td>
  @Html.Label("DOB:")
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Driver.Dob, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Driver.Dob)
</td>
```

Is there a built-in way offered by .net to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Create your own custom attribute.

```
[DateValidation]
public System.DateTime Dob { get; set; }

public class DateValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
  public override bool IsValid(object value) {
     DateTime dateValue;
     var date = DateTime.TryParse(value.toString(), out dateValue);
     // "var dateValue = (DateTime) value;" might work as well, let me know what does.
     return dateValue < DateTime.Now;
  }
}
```

Important: the name of the attribute class should end with `Attribute`.

Comment: I tried both ways, keeping the same class and method name from your example, but when I enter a date like "10/01/2014", it doesn't catch it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use [`IValidatableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx)...

So then:

```
public class MyViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Birthdate is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public System.DateTime Dob { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if(Dob >= DateTime.Today)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Dob date should be set in the past", new [] { "Dob" });
    }
}
```

Then just calling `ModelState.IsValid` in the controller worked just fine for me so far, but if you experience any problems with it, there are [other answers that tackle that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6431986/1180426)

Admittedly, in such a simple case it might be better and easier to create your own attribute per Jeroen's answer, but if you need any further and/or more complicated logic that may even involve other class members, then `IValidatableObject` is the built-in way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using JQuery DatePicker, follow [this link](http://www.nickharris.net/2010/08/asp-net-mvc-editor-template-for-jquery-datepicker/), change

```
@Html.TextBox("",  String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Model.HasValue ? Model : DateTime.Today), new { @class = "dp", @readonly = "readonly"})

<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function () {   
            $(".dp").datepicker({
                maxDate: new Date,
                dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy',
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true
            });
});

</script>
```