# IValidateObject not showing message mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My Model:

```
public class FPTAssetSummary : IValidatableObject
    {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "New Version")]
    public int ForatFrom { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Old Version")]
    public int ForatTo { get; set; }

    public List<FPTFORATExcel> FPTForatVersionList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(
        ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (ForatFrom <= ForatTo)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(
                "Old version must be higher than the new version");
        }
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ForatExcelCompare(FPTAssetSummary foratcompare)
    {

        var ExcelIDFrom = foratcompare.ForatFrom;
        var ExcelIDTo = foratcompare.ForatTo;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", new
        {
            ForatFrom = ExcelIDFrom,
            ForatTo = ExcelIDTo
        });
    }
```

Currently I am posting two integers from a view (2 dropdownboxes), to the controller below and passing the two values into the index with the two parameters (`ForatFrom` and `ForatTo`). 
However my `IValidationObject` method isn't returning the `ValidationResult` message. I think I need to check the model state in the `ForatExcelCompare` method, however I need to be able to return to the previous controller with the error message if the model state is false. Any Ideas?

Comment: How are you displaying the error message in the view? Are you using the ValidationSummary helper?

Comment: Yes sorry, forgot to mention that i have set the @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

Comment: Check out [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6431986/2779990).  It provides the following: `if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
    if (!model.Validated) {
        var validationResults = model.Validate(new ValidationContext(model, null, null));
        foreach (var error in validationResults)
            foreach (var memberName in error.MemberNames)
                ModelState.AddModelError(memberName, error.ErrorMessage);
    }

    return View(post);
}`