# Validate method is not being called on a model inside a viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I’m new to MVC.NET and can’t seem to understand why my validate function is not being called which sits inside of a MyModel class.

**MyModel:**

```
Public string Name { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
// validation logic which is not being called on post. 
}
```

When I post the form, I’m actually posting my ViewModel that has a property of MyModel.

**ViewModel:**

```
Public MyModel { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model)
{
    // this is always true??
    if(this.ModelState.IsValid) { blah blah }
}
```

The reason it’s always true is because my validation logic inside MyModel is not being called from the ViewModel on the POST.

This is probably a noob question but I have no idea.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I haven't got time to post code, sorry, but looking into "Custom Model Binders". Create a custom model binder for `ViewModel`, that is executed when `public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model)` is called. In the custom model binder you will be able to call the validation method.

Comment: Just expanding on Jason's comment, [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431478/how-to-force-mvc-to-validate-ivalidatableobject) should give you an idea how to go with `Custom Model Binder`.

Comment: Uh, this isn't MVVM--it's MVC.  Your "ViewModel" is a model.  The controller is...the controller.  And the cshtml file is the view.  Model-View-Controller.  MVVM frameworks for web applications typically live client side.  Angular and Knockout are two examples of an MVVM client-side framework.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the responses. I actually talked to a co-worker who informed me that in order to get the ViewModel to post and have the validation take place for the class referenced in the viewmodel I needed to inherit from IValidatableObject

```
public class MyModel : IValidatableObject
```

than I just needed needed to pass in ValidationContext validationContext into the Validate method.

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
}
```

And it worked! it called the validation method for MyModel upon posting ViewModel.

Comment: I see this is exactly what Michael was talking about in the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

You might also look into DataAnnotations for your validation requirements; it will probably result in much cleaner code in your model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[Required(ErrorMessage="Please supply a Name")]
[RegularExpression(@"^([A-Za-z]{1,50}$")]
Public string Name { get; set; }
```

...for example.