# How to programatically execute the ModelState validation in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I must run the validation of a specific model after it has been submitted.

I know there are the `ValidateModel/TryValidateModel` and `TryUpdateModel/UpdateModel` but that is not good enough.

I need to perform a `deep` model state validation of a model. I tried getting the validation of each property and inner properties individually but the ModelState entry does not get the prefix which is obviously necessary.

Comment: Have you tried watching input key value pairs? In a POST, all values in input tags are submitted to the server as key-value pairs. look at the dictionary in modelstate perhaps.

Comment: I know how things are done and what I asked is how do I get MVC to do the validation that it also does on the POST.

Comment: why can't you inherit from IValidatableObject and then call Validate() on the model.

Comment: Because I have custom data annotations that are tested and work in several field types that do server-side and client-side validation. I didn't ask for alternatives. All I am asking is if someone can please share a way of validating the whole model again the same way the model binder does before the request reaches the action method.

Comment: >Because I have custom data annotations<.  That important information you might want to put in the question.  like how are you validating and some of the "deep" model you are validating.  Given the limited information you provided.  having all your models inherit from IValidateableObject and calling Validate() on the root model would do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: you could also explain why ValidationModel isn't good enough.  what is it doing/not doing that makes it unacceptable.

Comment: @Fran, my apologies for the lack of information. You are right. Sorry about that. We need data annotations because we want to have server and client-side information and, in my opinion, it is much more desirable to annotation properties in view models than having methods implemented in our view models that validate imperatively.

Comment: This may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493800/how-can-i-tell-the-data-annotations-validator-to-also-validate-complex-child-pro
It seems you can't do it with attributes alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Validator.TryValidateObject` and `Validator.TryValidateProperty`.

This adds the errors to the input parameter `validationResults` and also sets the ModelState everytime (while deleting the model state error from the prior field).

It is not ideal but I get all errors and, for each error, I build the error key and save it a list.

At the end, I clear the model state and save all errors. It works. Thanks @Fran for his suggestion.