# Create a complex type model validation attribute with server and client validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation, model-validation

I'm trying to create an attribute that can validate a complex type both on the server and client side. This attribute will be used for required and non required complex types such as the following Address Class

```cs
public partial class AddressViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Address 1")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Address 2")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public virtual string Address2 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public virtual string City { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual string State { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    [DisplayName("Postal Code")]
    public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(2)]
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that this model could be required sometimes and optional other times. I know that I could simply create another `RequiredAddressViewModel` class that has the `Required` attribute associated with the properties I deem required. I feel like there could be a reusable solution, such as a ValidationAttribute.

I created the following classes and they work server side, but do not work for client side.

```cs
public class AddressIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public string Address1 { get; private set; }

    public string Address2 { get; private set; }

    public string City { get; private set; }

    public string State { get; private set; }

    public string PostalCode { get; private set; }

    public string Country { get; private set; }

    public bool IsRequired { get; private set; }

    public AddressIfAttribute(bool isRequired) : base("The field {0} is required.")
    {
        IsRequired = isRequired;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var address = value as AddressViewModel;
        Address1 = address.Address1;
        Address2 = address.Address2;
        City = address.City;
        State = address.State;
        Country = address.Country;
        PostalCode = address.PostalCode;

        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var context = new ValidationContext(address, null, null);

        Validator.TryValidateObject(address, context, results, true);

        if (results.Count == 0 && IsRequired)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address2))
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format(ErrorMessageString, validationContext.DisplayName));

        }
        else if (results.Count != 0)
        {
            var compositeResults = new CompositeValidationResult(string.Format("Validation for {0} failed!", validationContext.DisplayName));
            results.ForEach(compositeResults.AddResult);

            return compositeResults;
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ModelClientValidationAddressIfRule(string.Format(ErrorMessageString,metadata.GetDisplayName()), Address1, Address2, City, State, Country, PostalCode,IsRequired)
        };
    }
}

public class ModelClientValidationAddressIfRule : ModelClientValidationRule
{
    public ModelClientValidationAddressIfRule(string errorMessage, object address1, object address2, object city, object state, object country, object postalCode, bool isRequired)
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        ValidationType = "addressif";
        ValidationParameters.Add("address1", address1);
        ValidationParameters.Add("address2", address2);
        ValidationParameters.Add("city", city);
        ValidationParameters.Add("state", state);
        ValidationParameters.Add("country", country);
        ValidationParameters.Add("postalCode", postalCode);
        ValidationParameters.Add("isrequired", isRequired.ToString().ToLower());
    }
```

Since the `AddressIf` attribute is on a complex type the necessary markup isn't added and unobtrusive javascript doesn't validate these fields.

So if I want the rendered HTML to have the proper `data-*` fields, is my only solution to create another RequiredAddressViewModel? At this point, it might be the easiest.

Comment: No, it is not possible to get client side validation with you implementation. You could include  `bool IsRequired` property in your view model and then apply a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue("IsRequired")]` or similar attribute to each property of the view model

Comment: Alternatively, if its not required, don't generate any inputs for that model and it will be `null` in the POST method and no validation will be performed - I assume this model is a property of a parent model (side note: view models should not be partial classes)