# Blazor validation for custom class

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, blazor

I'm testing out Blazor and I've run into a validation issue. When validating a simple class I can just use annotations. If I have my own custom class inside though validation doesn't run for everything inside my custom class. The issue seems to be specific to Blazor since I can use this validation in ASP.

Here are my two simple models:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required]
    [Range(12, 400, ErrorMessage = "This works")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public KeyValue KeyValues { get; set; }
    public TestModel()
    {
        Count = 4;
        KeyValues = new KeyValue()
        {
            Key = 5,
            Value = "str"
        };
    }
}
```

And the KeyValue class

```
public class KeyValue
{
    [Required]
    [Range(10, 300, ErrorMessage = "This number check doesn't")]
    public int Key { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Nor the string one")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And that is my component. It validates the Model.Count property, but doesn't validate the nested class.

```
<EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="@DoStuff">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="number" bind="@Model.Count" class="form-control" placeholder="Condition property name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="number" bind="@Model.KeyValues.Key" class="form-control" placeholder="Condition property name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <InputText bind-Value="@Model.KeyValues.Value"></InputText>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell the Data Annotations validator to also validate complex child properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493800/how-can-i-tell-the-data-annotations-validator-to-also-validate-complex-child-pro)

Comment: The issue here isn't with validator itself, but with the properties of the nested classes. This kind of validation works in ASP, but doesn't in Blazor.

Comment: @ГеоргиДимитров Perhaps you should accept an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known limitation of Blazor, but you can work around it.

First, use the `OnSubmit` event on `<EditForm>` instead of `OnValidSubmit`. The method is passed an `EditContext` like so...

```
private void FormSubmitted(EditContext context)
{
  ...
}
```

If you use the following extension you can use the following code in your `FormSubmitted` method and it will not only validate your entire object tree but also update your UI according to the result.

```
{
  if (context.ValdiateObjectTree())
  {
    ... do whatever
  }
}
```

The extension...

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace PeterLeslieMorris.Blazor.Validation.Extensions
{
    public static class EditContextExtensions
    {
        static PropertyInfo IsModifiedProperty;
        static MethodInfo GetFieldStateMethod;

        /// <summary>
        /// Validates an entire object tree
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="editContext">The EditContext to validate the Model of</param>
        /// <returns>True if valid, otherwise false</returns>
        public static bool ValidateObjectTree(this EditContext editContext)
        {
            var validatedObjects = new HashSet<object>();
            ValidateObject(editContext, editContext.Model, validatedObjects);
            editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
            return !editContext.GetValidationMessages().Any();
        }

        public static void ValidateProperty(this EditContext editContext, FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier)
        {
            if (fieldIdentifier.Model == null)
                return;

            var propertyInfo = fieldIdentifier.Model.GetType().GetProperty(
                fieldIdentifier.FieldName,
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

            var validatedObjects = new HashSet<object>();
            ValidateProperty(editContext, fieldIdentifier.Model, propertyInfo, validatedObjects);
        }

        private static void ValidateObject(
            EditContext editContext,
            object instance,
            HashSet<object> validatedObjects)
        {
            if (instance == null)
                return;

            if (validatedObjects.Contains(instance))
                return;

            if (instance is IEnumerable && !(instance is string))
            {
                foreach (object value in (IEnumerable)instance)
                    ValidateObject(editContext, value, validatedObjects);
                return;
            }

            if (instance.GetType().Assembly == typeof(string).Assembly)
                return;

            validatedObjects.Add(instance);

            var properties = instance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                ValidateProperty(editContext, instance, property, validatedObjects);
        }

        private static void ValidateProperty(
            EditContext editContext,
            object instance,
            PropertyInfo property,
            HashSet<object> validatedObjects)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged(editContext, instance, property.Name);

            object value = property.GetValue(instance);
            ValidateObject(editContext, value, validatedObjects);
        }

        private static void NotifyPropertyChanged(
            EditContext editContext,
            object instance,
            string propertyName)
        {
            if (GetFieldStateMethod == null)
            {
                GetFieldStateMethod = editContext.GetType().GetMethod(
                    "GetFieldState",
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            }

            var fieldIdentifier = new FieldIdentifier(instance, propertyName);
            object fieldState = GetFieldStateMethod.Invoke(editContext, new object[] { fieldIdentifier, true });

            if (IsModifiedProperty == null)
            {
                IsModifiedProperty = fieldState.GetType().GetProperty(
                    "IsModified",
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            }

            object originalIsModified = IsModifiedProperty.GetValue(fieldState);
            editContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fieldIdentifier);
            IsModifiedProperty.SetValue(fieldState, originalIsModified);
        }

    }
}
```

You can find the extension source [here](https://github.com/mrpmorris/blazor-validation/blob/master/src/PeterLeslieMorris.Blazor.Validation/Extensions/EditContextExtensions.cs). You could alternatively use [Blazor-Validation](https://github.com/mrpmorris/blazor-validation), which also allows you to use [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/).

If you want a more in-depth understanding of how Blazor forms / validation works, you can read about it in this section of [Blazor University](https://blazor-university.com/forms/).

Answer (score 5):

In case someone else stumbles into this issue it isn't possible right now. It should be available in 3.0.0-preview8 according to this post
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10896